# Am I allowed to save basic user data from Facebook in my own web app's database?

Tags: facebook, legal, usage-data, facebook-graph

In general my app deals with data that is unrelated to Facebook but also includes a Graph API based app.

So it would be helpful for someone to login with Facebook (without registering in my own web app) and then save their email to allow direct communication with my user's web app.

This is not for spam of course.

Comment: So when you say "basic user's data" in the question, do you mean just the email address?

Comment: Yes, just email.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Facebook platform policy](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/) explains the rules. In particular:

> You may cache data you receive through use of the Facebook API in
> order to improve your application’s user experience, but you should
> try to keep the data up to date.
>
> ...
>
> By “basic account information” we mean: name, email, gender, birthday, current city, and profile picture URL.

So you can store it, but if they change their email address then you need to pick up that change.

Comment: Yes, I just reading [II. Storing and Using Data You Receive From Us](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/#data) Also say: If you stop using Platform or we disable your application, **you must delete all data** you have received through use of the Facebook API **unless**: **(a) it is basic account information; or (b) you have received explicit consent from the user to retain their data.** So we can store it and if you ask for explicit consent from the user we can stop worring about it. THX.-